# python telegram bot API как получить всех участников группы?

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram

python telegram bot API как получить всех участников группы?
Если я не состою в группе?Но информация открыта?

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению, сейчас нельзя получить данные о всех пользователях в чате.

Их можно посчитать используя **get_chat_members_count**, или узнать информацию о пользователе в чате используя **get_chat_member**.

Главное что бы бот находился в чате. Иначе он просто не сможет получить данные.

Answer (score 0):

Если ваш бот присутствует в группе, то используйте telegram API а не telegram bot API  и метод getFullChat, это полностью все данные о канале в том числе и участники